# Dockerfile parse error line 20: unknown instruction: NEW-WEBSITE

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image, .net-4.8

trying to create Dockerfile for my .net framework web project

```
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework:4.8-sdk As builder

    WORKDIR D:\src
    COPY *.sln .
    COPY Internal.Api.csproj .\Internal.Api\
    RUN nuget restore
    
    COPY . D:\src
    RUN msbuild Internal.Api.csproj /p:OutputPath=d:\out /p:Configuration=Release
    
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019
    SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference='Stop';"]
    
    ENV APP_ROOT=D:\web-app
    
    WORKDIR  ${APP_ROOT}
    RUN Remove-Website -Name 'Default Web Site';`
        New-Website -Name 'web-app' -Port 80 -PhysicalPath $env:APP_ROOT;`
        New-WebApplication -Name 'app' -Site 'web-app' -PhysicalPath $env:APP_ROOT`
        
    COPY --from=builder D:\out\-PublishedWebsites\Internal.Api .
```

But getting following error[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell Docker that the command continues on the next line by adding `\` at the end. Not the back-ticks that you're using now. Like this

```
RUN Remove-Website -Name 'Default Web Site'; \
    New-Website -Name 'web-app' -Port 80 -PhysicalPath $env:APP_ROOT; \
    New-WebApplication -Name 'app' -Site 'web-app' -PhysicalPath $env:APP_ROOT
```

Comment: Thank you @Hans Kilian that error is gone but now seeing this--   [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8.1:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: no match for platform in manifest sha256:d54f9db8de62932d1acba0a1153f796895457039c8a8ecfeca3868d5dec864f5: not found